# Next auth getSession with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am using `next-auth` `getSession` in API routes like this

```
const mySession = await getSession({ req });
```

I am certain that the type of the `mySession` is this

```
type SessionType = {
  user: {
    email: string;
  };
};
```

When I mouseover on `mySession` it displays like this

```
const mySession: Session | null
```

This can be either `null` or type of `Session`.

How do I override the type with the type `SessionType`

I tried this

```
 const mySession = await getSession<SessionType>({ req });
```

This gives me an error

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

How do I change the type of the `getSession` method?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the method can return null is because its possible that the user/caller of your api is in fact not authenticated. So I doubt you really want to do that. Instead you could make actual use of this like the following:

```
const session = getSession({req});

if(!session) return res.status(401).end();


// From now on session is sure to not be null and you can do whatever you want with it
```

If you actually have a legitimate use-case to change the value a session can have, maybe this is useful:

You are getting the Error because `getSession` is not expecting you to specify a type, or put differently, `getSession`is not implemented using generics.

What you can do to extend the Session is this:

1. Extend the returned object by [providing a session callback in the next auth options](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback)
2. Override the next-auth module

Both steps are described [here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#main-module)